# Gazebo Simulation: Person and Robot model interaction

Tags: husky, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Gazebo simulation where a Husky robot is looking for a person using its camera. Now that I manage to get this part working, I want the Husky robot to interact with the person it found. Here are some things I have in mind:

- The husky robot emits a sound using its speaker. When the person hears it, it moves.
- When the husky robot touches the person, the animated person in Gazebo stops moving.

In short, I want the Husky robot to interact (i.e. send commands and receive responses) with the simulation elements. Is this possible? It seems to be related to [Gazebo plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) and its [ROS API](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm), but it’s not clear to me yet (I’m quite new to ROS/Gazebo).

Any pointer/book/video/example would be greatly appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386060/gazebo-simulation:-person-and-robot-model-interaction/) by [cptanalatriste](https://answers.ros.org/users/80507/cptanalatriste/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
Just to help me understand better your question. Are you planning to interact with a virtual person or a real person in Gazebo? Not clear

Playing sounds, can be done using Python libraries for playing and recording sound: https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/

You can use the sensor information to detect objects and navigate accordingly including stopping. If you are planning to do people recognition, then you may be looking at using pytorch or tensorflow to train on detection. The simplest of methods would be to use a HAAR cascade for object detection.

In the spirit of one question, one answer. I suggest to focus your question on a specific issue you need support.

**Comment by [cptanalatriste](https://answers.ros.org/users/80507/cptanalatriste/) on 2021-09-16**:
Hi @osilva! Thanks for the answer. My focus on interacting with a "virtual" person on Gazebo: if my robot model emits a sound in a Gazebo simulation, how can I program the person model to react to the sound, if possible?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-18**:
@cptanalatriste The idea of "the robot touching a person" is going to be a problem. `move_base` goes to great lengths to **avoid** the robot getting too close to *any* obstacle. And in the real world, this would be quite a dangerous/unsafe action to program into any large, powerful robot like a Husky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With regards to human model take a look at this #q384541
or search for spawning human model. Once you load the model it’s like any other robot in gazebo. You can publish the sound and make your human model subscribe to it. If the sound is ON then you react.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1